# What novel was referenced in the pilot episode of Suits?

Tags: identification-request

This novel is referenced in the pilot of the tv show Suits.  However, it was only referenced very quickly and the title of the book wasn't given so hopefully the scene from the episode mirrors the book enough for someone to identify.

The scene from the show was a drug sting operation in a hotel.  Mike, the drug delivery person had to go to a room in the hotel.  When he reaches the floor of the room, he notices a bellhop helping someone try to get into his room.  This room is across the hall from the room he's supposed to go make his delivery.  He asks the bellhop about the pool at the hotel.  The bellhop replied they were nice but Mike remembered a sign that the pool was closed.

He then asked the patron for the time and notices a gun on him.  He walks by the room he's supposed to go to make the delivery and goes into the stairway.  He eventually ends up in the law interview meeting room where the interviewer asked him how he knew they were cops.  Mike's reply was he read a novel as a kid and it was the exact same thing.  He also said what drug dealer would ask a cop for the time with a suitcase full of pot and asked to throw them off.

Hopefully this is written clear enough on what was referenced in the scene and with enough details to identify the book.

Actually [here's the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImEnWAVRLU0) from the episode on youtube to better show what happened and what I'm asking about.